# Is there a way to obtain template argument type of base class without using "aliases, typedefs and using"?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, types, alias

Is there a way to obtain Type of base class template argument without "typedef's, aliases and using"? Here is my code...

I know i could define public "using Type = T" in my Class A and obtain the type from there, but i am searching for another way to do this.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class A {
public:
    virtual T doSomething() const = 0;
};

template <class T>
class B : public T {
    using BaseType = T;
    using Type = BaseType::A::???;
    
    // i want "Type" to be double when inheriting from class C
    // and to be int when inheriting from class D

public:
    Type doSomething() const override {
        return 0;
    }

    Type value;
};

class C : public A<double> {
public:
};

class D : public A<int> {
public:
};

int main() {
    B<C>    b1;
    B<D>    b2;
    
    std::cout << b1.doSomething() << "\n";
    std::cout << b2.doSomething() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cxnPEYh15

Comment: Yes i know about this solution but i am searching a way without using the "typedef"...

Comment: @MiroslavKrajcir `using` is the way. See how every C++ standard library template always has aliases on each template argument. But you can apply the same technique (with template template) to get `T` directly in `B`, without going through `first_template_type` helper.

Comment: *" am searching a way without using the "typedef"..."* Why? No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `using Type = decltype(std::declval<BaseType>().doSomething());` https://godbolt.org/z/ozTx6obsn

Comment: what you want is an alias of `T` from `A<T>`, hence there is no way to do that without using an alias

Comment: unfortunately what you want to do, without using any typedef or using declarations, requires some form of static reflection, which is not yet present in the standard. As @Yksisarvinen suggested, the standard way is a `using` declaration.